# what is the concept of text, routine , macro and differentiate between them

Tags: tandem

This is the example we are using those concepts here

```
?SECTION <program name> MACRO

?SECTION <program name> TEXT

?SECTION <program name> ROUTINE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly three types of TACL files Macro , Routine & Text.

**Text:-** It is simply means that we have bunch of commands we want to execute on Tandem so we create a Text type file.

**E.g.** here we want to print bunch of statements so we have created a print TEXT .

```
?SECTION print TEXT
#OUTPUT Hello1
#OUTPUT Hello2
#OUTPUT Hello3
```

**Routine:-** Routine have bunch of arguments which are compulsory to pass when we are executing Routine's on tandem.

**Macros:-** Macros have also have arguments but they are not compulsory to pass during execution.